# enable Flash light on my Android device Using AR Foundation

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, ar-foundation

I need a C# Code to enable Flash light on my Android device Using AR Foundation

Is it possible ??

`CameraManager camManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
String cameraId = null; // Usually back camera is at 0 position.

```
    try {
        cameraId = camManager.getCameraIdList()[0];
        camManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, true);   //Turn ON


    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }`
```